# Changing properties of the control that calls a Context Menu

Tags: vb.net, contextmenu

I have 10 PictureBox on a windows form (created in Design View) and a context menu strip is attached to each of them. I am trying to set the property of the PictureBox using the context menu.

For eg If the user selects Red from the context menu a Red picture shows up

I can get the the name of the control that popped the Context Menu strip by

```
cmStrp1.SourceControl.Name
```

Is there any way I can use the cmStrp1.SourceControl.Name to get the object/control and set its properties

Comment: VB.NET

*random text to get this posted*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `cmStrp1.SourceControl` instead of `cmStrp1.SourceControl.Name`. You need to cast the control to a `PictureBox` before using it.

Comment: can you add some code? I don't know how to typecast cmStrp1.SourceControl

Comment: @Kartik: How would you typecast `Integer`?